# Does a New Zealander need a transit visa for Australia?

Tags: australia, transit-visas, new-zealand-citizens

I'm a New Zealander who is flying from India to Auckland with a change over in Australia.

Do I need a visa?

Answer (score 12):

As a New Zealand citizen, you can travel to and stay in Australia for any length of time and for any reason. Since Australia needs a name for this category of visitor, they have something called a ["Special Category Visa" (SCV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Category_Visa) which is only issued to New Zealand citizens. There is no specific paperwork associated with this visa (just the normal passenger arrival card which everybody fills out), and it's only granted upon arrival. You show up, they may or may not stamp your passport, and you walk in.

Note that some people are not eligible for the SCV, such as those who have criminal records or severe health problems. Such people must apply for a specific visitor visa instead.

To answer your implied question, no you do not need to do any advance paperwork before arriving in Australia. As long as you are holding a New Zealand passport, there should be no problems whatsoever.

Comment: This is not related to the question but are there restrictions if one wants to travel there for work (i.e. is criminal records the only exception)?

Comment: @TypoCubeᵀᴹ: Work is permitted on an SCV. There are thousands of Kiwis living and working in Australia (and vice versa, as the arrangement is bilateral).

Comment: Thnx. I wasn't sure if there was some other type of work visa.

Comment: You can get the SCV with a criminal record, it's just that they are allowed to refuse you because of it. Essentially you can't use the quick lines, they'll ask you for details, then let you in (assuming it is minor).

Answer (score 9):

For a stay in the transit area of less than 8 hours you do not need a visa. Courtesy [KLM](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/timatic.htm):

> / 19DEC16 / 1256 UTC
>
> National New Zealand (NZ)       /Embarkation India (IN) Transit
>   Australia (AU)          /Destination New Zealand (NZ) ALSO CHECK
>   DESTINATION INFORMATION BELOW
>
> Australia (AU)
>
> VISA NOT REQUIRED.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Nationals of New Zealand who decide to enter Australia or who have a transit time of more than 8 hours and are required to leave the transit area must apply for a Special Category Visa (SCV) when clearing immigration by presenting a valid passport and completing a passenger card.